# reliable multicast in C#

Tags: c#, networking, network-programming, messaging, network-protocols

what are my options for reliable multicast in c# /.Net 3.5?

I don’t want to use MSMQ.

I am open to commercial as well as open source options.

Thanks

Comment: What do you have against MSMQ?

Comment: In some environments you can't rely on the MSMQ service being enableable.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [EmCaster](http://code.google.com/p/emcaster/)

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.29west.com/](http://29west.com) claims to be the lowest latency reliable multicast solution available. I have not verified this claim, but in talking to them, it seems that their biggest competition is not some other vendor, but in house developemnt. Why not just set up your own multicast group, and use it directly? Chapter 21 of "Unix Network Programming Volume 1" describes how to do this.

Comment: Yeah, they also claim an oxymoron of remote/local DMA too. It's just a socket and most hardware these days bypasses the CPU on modern OS-es plus interfaces/drivers are far smarter. But big corps love to buy into simple socket servers for decades, amazing how far marketing a box of matches can go. Completely agree with direct use and upvoting for that part; but someone sooner or later will hit on alarmingly spreading 30east LBM (largescale blx marketing) as if network is not the bottleneck. – Majkara Tito 0 secs ago

Comment: One transport lbm supports is DMA over Infiniband.  It's not an oxymoron in that context.

Answer (score 1):

[ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) is an excellent product by the Apache organization. There's bindings for lots of languages, including C#.

In the commercial world [Tibco EMS](http://www.tibco.com/software/messaging/enterprise-message-service/default.jsp) is a good choice. Its got bindings for C# and Java.

Comment: Tibco EMS is the best I've worked with. Active MQ is ok but doesn't actually use Multicasting. If you like you can roll your own rather easily. I have the code on my site here: http://jarloo.com/code/networking/c-udp-multicasting-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

The best one I've used, after evaluating a bunch was [Mesongo RMF](http://www.mesongo.com/rmf.aspx) - it had a really clean API and good monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

The pragmatic variant, PGM, it's in your Windows image, look for it on say server 2003, even XP and friends.. there are socket options for it (Rdm or similar).