# Is there a JGroups equivalent for .NET

Tags: .net, jgroups

Does anybody know of a JGroups equivalent for .NET, with similar features for cluster management and data distribution?

/Jon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888604/reliable-multicast-in-c might give you some further hints.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Also search for "Group Communication Toolkit in .NET" on this page:

[JGroups - Success Stories](http://www.jgroups.org/success.html)

Answer (score 0):

NServiceBus will give you equivalent features.